# How to setup kubernetes dashboard with an ingess controller

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, kubernetes-ingress

I am very new to the idea of `kubernetes`. 
I found some good tutorials online to get my `kubernetes` cluster up & running.
Right Now I want to add a `kubernetes` dashboard to my cluster so that it would be easy and good to have a page where I can watch how my pods and node's react (even do I'm more of a CLI guy, some GUI is not bad). 
I've downloaded the dashboard pod and it's up and running. Because the kubernetes cluster is running on a Raspberry Pi cluster I've set up a NodePort to access it from outside my cluster. But I've come to some problems where I can't find any problems too online.

1. In my Linux host machine I can access the kubernetes dashboard but somehow in my Linux machine, my browsers won't add the cert exception.
2. Some people online are convinced that NodePort is not safe enough. So I've done some research on other possibilities. I am very interested in the ingress controller to connect my dashboard. But I didn't find any good and full documentation how to set up an ingress controller (and more importantly what is happening, cause there are a lot of yaml files online and they say just run this but i have no clue what he is doing).

Can someone direct me to the right documentation/tutorial / or give me any help for my Kube dashboard?

Comment: Have you managed to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone in an other forum send me this tutorial which was very helpfull. I'll share it here also for all the people who've came to this post with the same question.

https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/

Comment: Very new to kubernetes: however the tutorial that you suggest has a very interesting approach: at the end it puts a service with NodePort in front of nginx-ingress. I thought ingress itself was to replace services with NodePorts and did not need another layer to be accessible. Also most a bunch of installations steps in that tutorial are taken care by https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to use in the deployment is Ingress so lets start with it.

Firstly you should create an Ingress controller, you can find the [Installation Guide here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/deploy)

The most relevant is the first part - Generic Deployment which includes following:

Namespace for the Ingress controller installation:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/namespace.yaml \ | kubectl apply -f -
```

Default backend for Ingress controller:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/default-backend.yaml \ | kubectl apply -f -
```

And config maps:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/configmap.yaml \ | kubectl apply -f - 
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/tcp-services-configmap.yaml \ | kubectl apply -f - 
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/udp-services-configmap.yaml \ | kubectl apply -f -
```

Because you deployed your cluster on Raspberry Pi, all of this needs to be created manually.

After the Ingress controller is installed you can deploy specific configuration for your Ingress with rules to route traffic to your service.

Here is an example of Ingress yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: endpoint-to-the-world
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your-external-address-for-the-cluster
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /console
        backend:
          serviceName: kubernetes-dashboard
          servicePort: 443
      - path: /some-other-path
        backend:
          serviceName: different-service
          servicePort: 22
```

This will act like an external proxy for your cluster and you can route all traffic to any service. More details can be [read here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

This should be enough to have Kubernetes Dashboard exposed.